# Transactions Pending - Balance 0

Tags: transaction, wallet

I have had my IOTA in at Bitfinex account for a while now, and decided to move it over to the app. After a while the transaction was at 0 and showing pending, but after browsing around I saw to reattach. After doing that, I can now see the transaction and amount, twice in my history both as pending.
I am wondering how to get it to show up in my balance, and go through the process to confirmed, been a few hours now and balance still at 0.
It is within https://iotasear.ch/bundle/KPOKKSZQXUJPJ9GNHYB9GYFFLIIQCDGUZTKZDWKTQYGTJHW9UJBQPVIIARHTTZCIGJGAGYBSCWJQ9IRTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to wait, sometimes it takes a bit for transactions to confirm. I think Bitfinex will reattach it until it confirms.

Comment: This is accurate --- sometimes, it takes longer. You can also try switching nodes.

Comment: Seems to have shown up now, was just a tad concerned after seeing people say it only takes minutes. All good now.  
Guessing its totally fine with my history having 8 transfers and 5 addresses?

Comment: My balance has been zero for weeks, I have IOTAs in the tangle somewhere.  Reattaching and different nodes did not work.